# Cannot connect to my AWS RDS instance from my local computer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-vpc

I set a new MariaDB RDS instance in AWS and added Inboun and Outbound rules to Security Groups but when I try to connect to the RDS Endpoint via mysql console I am always getting this error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db-xxxxxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060 "Unknown error")

I am newbie in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an externally accessible instance in RDS. Publicly accessible has to be true.

Comment: the Public accessibility feature is already set to True.. And added inbound and outbound rules..

Comment: After searching and testing many updates, I came to solve the issue which was related tzo ACL configuration